# Request uri has problem for box.com integration

Tags: integration

when i preview my page url is

```
https://cloudzigzag-dev-ed--lightning-zag.ap7.visual.force.com/apex/BoxIntegration
```

in controller i have set

```
  private string redirect_uri = 'https://zag.ap7.visual.force.com/apex/BoxIntegration';
```

when i am trying to authenticate it shows below error

Error: **redirect_uri_mismatch**
 Show Error Details

response_type=code

redirect_uri=https://zag.ap7.visual.force.com/apex/BoxIntegration

state=security_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

client_id=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

Comment: As the error message clearly mention. Redirect URL must be exact same as you given in box app. So you need to pass the VF page URL in parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the error is related to redirect uri from box.

hope this helps.

Comment: yes i forgot to mention in box.com request uri...thanks